# Descending group actions to coverings

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-actions, covering-spaces

Let $X$ be a path-connected space with universal cover $\widetilde{X}$, let $Y$ be another covering of $X$

$$
\widetilde{X} \hspace{1cm} \\
\searrow \\
\downarrow\hspace{.5cm} Y\\
\hspace{.25cm}\swarrow\\
X \quad\quad
$$

and let $G \curvearrowright \widetilde{X}$ be a continuous group action on $\widetilde{X}$ *which commutes with the action of the fundamental group by deck transformations*.

Then the action descends to $Y$ in the following way: After choosing base points we know that $Y \cong \widetilde{X}/U$ for some subgroup $U$ of $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ according to the classification theorem for coverings. Now setting
$$
g(Ux) = U(gx)
$$
for $g \in G$ and $Ux \in Y$ we get a group action on $Y$.

**Questions:**

- I'm curious: Is there a more elegant description of the descended action on $Y$ that avoids the use of base points and writing $Y$ as $\widetilde{X}/U$? Maybe some uniqueness criteria or universal property?
  (also is it even independent of the choice of base point?)
- If the spaces are smooth manifolds and the action is smooth, will the descended action be smooth too? I would certainly think so, but I don't know how to prove it.